In .net core I want to get API through the two tables
In .Net core I have two tables with Buyer,
and the relation table as RicePrice:
    public class Buyer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int RiceId { get; set; }
        public RicePrice RicePrice { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RiceId")]
        public int Outputt { get; set; }
    }
    public class RicePrice
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        //Navigation property for related Customer
        public ICollection<Buyer> Buyers { get; set; }
    }

RicePrice is an relation table where the values are stored, in the Buyer table I have id, RiceId as an foreign key and quantity and result. Now in the result I want to print the values as the Quantity is given by the user and in the RicePrice table stored values should be fetch by the get and the result should be stored by multiplication. Please give me the get and post method of it.
I want to get the controller code where the multiplication are done and how to fetch the values using the get method and post method.

Please include any text as text within the question rather than as screenshots, unless the issue may only be seen through the use of a screenshot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Base on the entity, you could write controller like this:
        //post buyerId and quantity to update table "quantity" value and calulate output
        [HttpPost("SetQuantity")]
        public void SetQuantiy(int buyerId,int Quantiy)
        {
            var buyer=_dbContext.Buyers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == buyerId);
            buyer.Quantity = Quantiy;
            buyer.Outputt = Quantiy * buyer.RicePrice.Price;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        //get output by userId
        [HttpGet("GetOutPut")]
        public int GetOutput(int buyerId)
        {
            var buyer = _dbContext.Buyers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == buyerId);
            return buyer.Outputt;
        }

